# how to get values of certain attributes of a item with similar class name from a particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get all values of data attributes of 'coin-type' and 'coin-name' and 'coin-rank' from dom

Web  page contains following code.

```js
// I tried the following but not working

var xclassget = document.getElementsByClassName('black-p stacard caading');
var nodes = [],
  values = [];
for (var att, i = 0, atts = xclassget.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++) {
  att = atts[i];
  nodes.push(att.nodeName);
  values.push(att.nodeValue);
}
```

```html
    <article class="black-p stacard caading"
               coin-type="pageingx"
               coin-name="moonpa"
               coin-rank="1">
    
    
     <article class="black-p stacard caading"
               coin-type="YYYYYYY"
               coin-name="XXXXXX"
               coin-rank="Z">
    
    <article class="black-p stacard caading"
               coin-type="YYYYYYY"
               coin-name="XXXXXX"
               coin-rank="Z">
```

Comment: I created you a snippet. Please complete it to make a [mcve]

Comment: I see a lot of the responses use jQuery, probably because you used the jQuery tag. I will say that, unless you have another need for jQuery, I wouldn't recommend bringing it in just for this problem--it's easy enough to solve with vanilla js.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/e6tvaohr/ try if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am I understanding your requirements correctly, I think you may just want to access attributes using the `getAttribute` method.

```js
var xclassget = document.getElementsByClassName('black-p stacard caading');

var nodes = [];
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < xclassget.length; i++) {
  nodes.push(xclassget[i]);
  values.push({
    coinType: xclassget[i].getAttribute('coin-type'),
    coinName: xclassget[i].getAttribute('coin-name'),
    coinRank: xclassget[i].getAttribute('coin-rank')
  });
}

console.log(nodes, values);
```

```html
<article class="black-p stacard caading"
           coin-type="pageingx"
           coin-name="moonpa"
           coin-rank="1">
</article>

<article class="black-p stacard caading"
           coin-type="YYYYYYY"
           coin-name="XXXXXX"
           coin-rank="Z">
</article>

<article class="black-p stacard caading"
           coin-type="YYYYYYY"
           coin-name="XXXXXX"
           coin-rank="Z">
</article>
```

Based on the additional questions in the comments of this answer, you can manipulate the values array as you see fit. For example, if you just want a comma-separated string value of all the coin names, you could do the following:

```
console.log(values.map(value => value.coinName).join(', '))
```

Or, if you want to do a comma-separated string value of both the coin names and coin types:

```
console.log(values.map(value => `CoinName: ${value.coinName} | CoinType: ${value.coinType}`).join(', '))
```

Comment: hi @nick this is great. but how to get an array of all the values of coin-name? i tried just console.log( values); but not getting?

Comment: If you just want an array of coin-names, you could use the map function. something like `console.log(values.map(value => value.coinName))`

Comment: HI NICK, i need a variable which contains all coinNames values separated by a delimiter comma  like "coin 1,coin 2, coin 3"

Comment: Okay so something more like `console.log(values.map(value => value.coinName).join(', '))`?

Comment: perfect then one last query how to concatenate coiname and coin type as ---- CoinName: coin1 | CoinType: XXX, CoinName: coin2 | CoinType: YYYY, CoinName: coin3 | CoinType: ZZZ

Comment: Really just the same type of operation except use both values in the map function: `console.log(values.map(value => \`CoinName: ${value.coinName} | CoinType: ${value.coinType}\`).join(', '))`. I'll update my response with all these follow-ups since that's more appropriate

Comment: Hi nick all good however when i put this code in my tool my build is failed giving me this error---    there was an error minimizing custom code unexpected token (>)   I tried to put this code in the top of the js /*jshint esversion: 6 */ still am getting this errror and my build is unsuccessful pls help

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done with jquery

```js
var types = [],names = [] ,ranks = [];
$('.black-p.stacard.caading').each(function(){
  var CoinType = $(this).attr('coin-type');
  var CoinName = $(this).attr('coin-name');
  var CoinRank = $(this).attr('coin-rank');
  types.push(CoinType);
  names.push(CoinName);
  ranks.push(CoinRank);
});
console.log(types);
console.log(names);
console.log(ranks);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="black-p stacard caading"
           coin-type="pageingx"
           coin-name="moonpa"
           coin-rank="1"></article>


 <article class="black-p stacard caading"
           coin-type="YYYYYYY"
           coin-name="XXXXXX"
           coin-rank="Z"></article>

<article class="black-p stacard caading"
           coin-type="YYYYYYY"
           coin-name="XXXXXX"
           coin-rank="Z"></article>
```

Comment: I would recommend a solution without jQuery, seems unnecessary in this case. Even though the question is tagged with jQuery, it seems like he isn't using it considering he's using the js `getElementsByClassName` method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// jQuery

$(".black-p").each(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  console.log($this.attr("coin-type"))
});


// Javascript 
const xclassget = document.getElementsByClassName('black-p');

for (let i = 0; i < xclassget.length; i++) {
  console.log(xclassget[i].getAttribute("coin-type"));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="black-p stacard caading" coin-type="pageingx" coin-name="moonpa" coin-rank="1">


  <article class="black-p stacard caading" coin-type="YYYYYYY" coin-name="XXXXXX" coin-rank="Z">

    <article class="black-p stacard caading" coin-type="YYYYYYY" coin-name="XXXXXX" coin-rank="Z">
```

Comment: I would recommend a solution without jQuery, seems unnecessary in this case. Even though the question is tagged with jQuery, it seems like he isn't using it considering he's using the js `getElementsByClassName` method.

Comment: hi @aziz thanks for this to push it into array should i use define  var nodes = []; and then inside the loop

nodes.push(xclassget[i].getAttribute("coin-type"));

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example without jQuery. I'm not entirely sure the data object you're looking to end up with but once you have each element in the loop it's a matter of plucking out what you need.

```
var xclassget=document.getElementsByClassName('black-p stacard caading');
var attributes = []
Object.keys(xclassget).forEach(function(el) {
  var element = xclassget[el]
  attributes.push({
    'coin-value': element.attributes['coin-type'].value,
    'coin-name': element.attributes['coin-name'].value,
    'coin-rank': element.attributes['coin-rank'].value,
    })

})

console.log(attributes)
```